# regex - ignore whitespace from the beginning of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to validate a string into the jquery textcomplete.
Now my strings are arragned on multiple lines, a single line may have a couple key = value or multiple separated by commas
like:

```
key1=value1, mkey2 = value2;
  input3 =  value3
```

The expression I need must match the left operand of the expression

What I did:

```
/(?:,\s*|^\s|^|,)(?:\s*)([^=]\w*)/
```

My issue is that it instead of just returning

```
"key1" "mkey2" "input3"
```

it returns

```
["key1", "key1"], [", mkey2", "mkey2"] , ["   input3", "input3"]
```

But I'm expecting (actually jQuery.textcomplete is expecting)

```
["key1"], ["mkey2"] , ["input3"]
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xqkt05ja/)

EDIT: JS Code (previously was only on jfiddle)

```js
var items = [
    "key_1", 
    "key_2", 
    "key",
    "halt",
    "keybone",
    "klingon",
    "kabum"
    ];

$('#myTextArea1').textcomplete(
[{
    match: /[^=](\w*)$/,
    index: 1, // default = 2
    search: function (term, callback) {
        term = term.toLowerCase();
        callback($.map(items, function (item) {
            return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) >= 0 ? item : null;
        }));
    },
    replace: function (item) {
        return '' + item + ' = ';
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Maybe I miss something, but isn't Query.textcomplete expecting this? `["key1", "mkey2", "input3"]`

Comment: That is the list of "keys" that must match, sorry, I realized I didn't put here the jfiddle code. I was looking for the matching expression (the one that takes into the typed text and matches it with the array of choices)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're calling it, but try this out:

```
\s*(\w+)\s*=
```

Comment: No, it has the issue that when I hit enter it's get ignored. NOTE: I added a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

This is the RegEx I was looking for:

```regex
/(?<=^|,\s|,)(\w+(?=[=]|$))/m
```

What does it do?

• `(?<=^|,\s|,)` is a lookbehind that checks if the string is the beginning `^`, is `,`  or `,`

• `(\w+(?=[=]|$))` could be decomposed in two sub-expressions:

<> `\w+` that matches a word of at least a letter or digit POSIX `[:alnum:]` is not supported in JS

<> `(?=[=]|$)` is a lookahead that keeps the expression only if we're at the end of text `$` or the next character is not a `=`